# dealing with multiple users files on server

Tags: php

I making script which downloads then uploads files, but since i'm using foreach loop to loop through files in folder there will be problem when two users use the script at the same time because it will upload files from the first user and vice versa.
What is the usual solution to this?
To make random named folder when the script is started, just for that one session? Then download and upload from that folder?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this in a way to name every downloaded files using time() function and then every filename was different

```
foreach($down_urls as $down_url) 
    $filename = time();
```

Comment: Unless two people try it at the same time (within the same second).

Comment: you're right, but I don't think question also deserve downvote, it's still valid question